# View not refreshing when model change is called from child page (Ionic & Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic 3.20 with Angular 5.2.9 and I am having a problem with content refreshing after model is changed. I am new to all of this - I am probably missing something pretty basic.

In my view I have this element:

```
    <ion-item-sliding #slidingElement *ngFor="let item of this.myService.myList?.firstLevel.secondLevel">
```

In service `myService` I have this two functions:

```
    public myList: Array;

    getListOfData(): Observable {
        return  this.http.get(`service_endpoint_url`);
    }

    retrieveListOfData() {
        this.getListOfData().subscribe((result) => {
            this.myList = result;
            this.counter = this.myList['firstLevel'].length;
        });
    }
```

On first load (on `ngOnInit`) `this.myService.retrieveListOfData()` is called and view is successfully rendered. When I make action on specific item in list, list should be refreshed (this specific item should not be present in list any more). I am doing it this way:

```
    this.actionService.DoAction().subscribe((result) => {
        if(result == 'success') {
            this.myService.retrieveListOfData();
        }
    });
```

It works, if this code is called within the same page (where the list of items is).

But if I do it within detail page of specific item ("child" page, accessed on list item click), I can see in console, that variable `this.myList` is being changed but the view (list of items) is not rerendered when page with list of items is shown. Code:

```
    this.actionService.DoAction().subscribe((result) => {
        if(result == 'success') {
            this.myService.retrieveListOfData();
            //goes from detail page of specific item back to page with list of items
            this.app.getRootNav().popToRoot();
        }
    });
```

It has probably something to do with Zone? How can I properly refresh list of items from detail page of specific item?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 2018-05-14:** I found what the problem in my app was. We implemented lazy loading of modules. Because of that service was not shared between components as a singleton - instead of that every component ran it's isntance of a service. I implemented solution presented in [this blog post](https://medium.com/@chrishouse/when-to-use-angulars-forroot-method-400094a0ebb7).

I also found out that my nomenclature in this question was a little bit off - mentioned components are not siblings (not in "Angular way"). I am leaving Joshua's answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular doesn't detect changes of variables in an injected service.

There are two ways to produce what you want.

**Output Emitter**: use an output emitter in your detail (child) page to notify the master (parent) page of the changes.

In child.component.ts:

```
@Output() listChanged = new EventEmitter<void>();

this.actionService.DoAction().subscribe((result) => {
    if(result == 'success') {
        this.myService.retrieveListOfData();
        this.listChanged.emit();
        //goes from detail page of specific item back to page with list of items
        this.app.getRootNav().popToRoot();
    }
});
```

In parent.component.ts, add this to the child component:
`(listChanged)="retrieveListOfData()"`

**Observables**: configure your list in the service a Subject and subscribe to it in your components, instead of storing the data in the variable, push the data into the using Subject.next(data)

Comment: Hi Joshua! I didn't have time to implement your suggestion yet but I believe you pointed me to the right direction. I would gladly give you +1, but sadly I don't have enough reputation points. :( Thanks for your time!

Comment: Glad I helped, kindly check the answer as correct or write your answer for the question yourself when you manage to produce what you want.

Comment: I checked your answer as correct. I'll post my results here when I manage to implement it.

Comment: I found out what the problem was (I edited my question).